# displaying multiple loops that have multiple lines in a row instead of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x

My programming prof is not the easiest to follow and I swear he didn't cover this in class. He had us write multiple nested loops to draw 4 patterns. The second part of the question is to modify the program to display the patterns side by side instead of vertically... how do I do this?

Here is my existing code.

```
print(" Pattern A ")

for i in range (0,7):

    for k in range(1+i,0):

        print(end=" ")

    for j in range (1,i+1):

        print (j, end=" ")

    print()

print(" Pattern B ")

print()

for i in range (6,-1,-1):

    for k in range(1+i,0):

        print(end=" ")

    for j in range (1,i+1):

        print (j, end=" ")

    print()

print(" Pattern C ")

d=6

for i in range (0,7):

    for k in range(d):

        print(end="  ")

    d+=-1

    for j in range (i,0,-1):

        print (j, end=" ")

    print()

print(" Pattern D ")

d=0

print()

for i in range (6,-1,-1):

    for k in range(d):

        print(end="  ")

    d+=1    

    for j in range (1,i+1):

        print (j, end=" ")

    print()
```

I need

PAT A   PAT B   PAT C   PAT D

instead of

PAT A
PAT B
PAT C
PAT D

Comment: Are the patterns constant, or do they vary from line to line?

Comment: all the patterns are different

Comment: You can use "," for it.

Comment: they make different stair cases with numbers 1-6

Comment: this is an excellent question and normally way more trouble then it is worth, printing multi-line graphics side by side requires printing **all patterns simultaneously line by line** which cannot easily be done with the way you use the variable `d`.  I can't really post an answer without solving your homework for you but I wish you luck!

Comment: my entire class is searching for a solution to this issue.

Comment: that doesn't surprise me, it's not really an easy thing to do... ok I will post an answer...

Answer (score 0):

If the patterns are strings - append them to a list instead of print the result individually.

```
a = ['PAT A','PAT B','PAT C','PAT D']
' '.join(a)
'PAT A PAT B PAT C PAT D'
```

Comment: if you run the program provided you will see that this is not what was asked

Answer (score 0):

First off, *this is easier to do in a gui then on the terminal*:

```
import tkinter as tk

class WritableLabel(tk.Label):
    def write(self,text):
        self['text']+=text

root = tk.Tk()
box1 = WritableLabel(root)
box1.grid(column=1,row=0)

box2 = WritableLabel(root)
box2.grid(column=2,row=0)

box3 = WritableLabel(root)
box3.grid(column=3,row=0)

box4 = WritableLabel(root)
box4.grid(column=4,row=0)
```

then you can specify which box to place text in with `file=box#` in the print statement:

```
print(" Pattern A ",file=box1) 
...
      print (j, end=" ",file=box3)
```

and do `root.mainloop()` at the end.  Although this is kind of overkill for just a terminal solution, unfortunately that isn't all that much better...

---

to print multi-line texts side by side requires printing a line from each of them, then moving to the next line instead of handling each one separately.  The underlining requirement is that the width of each line in a pattern must be the same width, which yours do not. (`range(i+1,0)` doesn't actually do anything but it is along the right path)

In addition to this without the use of separate streams of execution (see generator approach below) each pattern needs to be able to print by knowing its line number and nothing else (you need to phase out the use of `d` variable, and make each one work with `range(0,7)` instead of `range(6,-1,-1)`)

once the above requirements are met you can just delete the `for` loops separating each pattern so that it looks something like this to do a line for each pattern before going to next line:

```
#This doesn't work but is a sort of template, will work if you 
print(" Pattern A "," Pattern B "," Pattern C "," Pattern D ")
#d=0
for i in range (0,7):
    #A
    for k in range(1+i,0):
        print(end=" ")
    for j in range (1,i+1):
        print (j, end=" ")
##### this separation would be removed
##    print() 
##
##print(" Pattern B ")
##
##print()
##
##for i in range (6,-1,-1):

    #B
    for k in range(1+i,0):
        print(end=" ")
    for j in range (1,i+1):
        print (j, end=" ")

    #C       
    for k in range(d):
        print(end="  ")
    #d+=-1
    for j in range (i,0,-1):
        print (j, end=" ")

    #D        
    for k in range(d):
        print(end="  ")
    #d+=1    
    for j in range (1,i+1):
        print (j, end=" ")

    print() #Go to next line
```

---

you can also do an approach with generators that generate each individual line although this is probably beyond your understanding at the moment: (which is why I don't feel bad including it on a homework question :P)

```
def pat1():
    for i in range (0,7):
        line = ""
        for k in range(1+i,0):

            line+=" "

        for j in range (1,i+1):

            line+= str(j) + " "

        yield line


def pat3():
    d=6

    for i in range (0,7):
        line = ""
        for k in range(d):

            line+="  "

        d+=-1

        for j in range (i,0,-1):

            line+=str(j) + " "

        yield line

pattern1_gen = pat1()
pattern3_gen = pat3()

try:
    while True:
        print(next(pattern1_gen),next(pattern3_gen))
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

but notice that the spacing is all wrong because pattern A is not spacing itself correctly. (you can use line.ljust(13) though)

Comment: this works great! thank you so much. allot of appreciation for giving me a solution instead of an answer! I understand for loops much better now. not posting my code so others can get what i got out of this post!